# C# app crashes on exit after using C++ function with delegates

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, dllimport

My C# app needs to talk with a DLL written in C++. I don't have the code of this DLL, but I have the code for a demo app (also in C++) that uses the DLL and works.

Here's the interesting code from the C++ demo app. It has two functions, one of which accepts a callback set of 4 delegates.

```
typedef BOOL (CBAPI* OPENSCANNERSDK)(HWND hwnd, TCallBackSet* callbackSet, wchar_t* configPath);
typedef void (CBAPI* CLOSESCANNERSDK)();

typedef struct              TCallBackSet
{
    TOnScannerStatusEvent   scannerStatusEvent;
    TOnScannerNotifyEvent   scannerNotifyEvent;
    TOnRFIDStatusEvent      rfidStatusEvent;
    TOnRFIDNotifyEvent      rfidNotifyEvent;
} TCallBackSet;

typedef void        (cdecl* TOnScannerStatusEvent   )   (int scannerStatus);
typedef void        (cdecl* TOnScannerNotifyEvent)      (int scannerNotify, int lParam);
typedef void        (cdecl* TOnRFIDStatusEvent      )   (int rfidStatus);
typedef void        (cdecl* TOnRFIDNotifyEvent      )   (int rfidnotify);
```

So, I have to call OpenScannerSDK, pass a callback set with pointers to some functions, do some stuff, and finally call CloseScannerSDK.

I have declared this in my C# app like so:

```
[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "_OpenScannerSDK")]
extern public static bool OpenScannerSDK(IntPtr hwnd, TCallBackSet callbackSet, 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string configPath);

[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "_CloseScannerSDK")]
extern public static void CloseScannerSDK();

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class TCallBackSet
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void TOnScannerStatusEvent(int scannerStatus);

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public TOnScannerStatusEvent ScannerStatusEvent;

    (I have removed the other 3 callbacks for brevity)
}
```

Finally I use the library like so:

```
var callback = new TCallBackSet() { ... set the delegates ... }
OpenScannerSDK(IntPtr.Zero, callback, ".");
... do other stuff...
CloseScannerSDK();
```

All this seems to work - both OpenScannerSDK and CloseScannerSDK and all the others I use between them work correctly. The problem is that as soon as the application tries to exit, I get an APPCRASH in KERNELBASE.dll. I don't see any relevant information in the crash report file. I have noticed that if I do not call OpenScannerSDK, but just some other functions of the DLL that are not related to delegates, the APPCRASH doesn't happen.

I also tried GC.KeepAlive for the delegates, no effect.

Comment: Does the C++ API make a copy of the `TCallbackSet`, or store a pointer to the one you passed in?

Comment: I do not have the code of the C++ DLL, so I do not know its internal workings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone interested, here is the final working solution.

First, CallBackSet is defined like so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CallBackSet
{
    public IntPtr ScannerStatusEvent;
    public IntPtr ScannerNotifyEvent;
    public IntPtr RfidStatusEvent;
    public IntPtr RfidNotifyEvent;
}
```

And then:

```
OnScannerStatusEvent onScannerStatus = (ScannerStatus status) => {...};
OnScannerNotifyEvent onScannerNotify = (ScannerNotify notify, short lparam) => {...};
OnRfidStatusEvent onRfidStatus = (RfidStatus status) => {...};
OnRfidNotifyEvent onRfidNotify = (RfidNotify notify) => {...};

GCHandle.Alloc(onScannerStatus);
GCHandle.Alloc(onScannerNotify);
GCHandle.Alloc(onRfidStatus);
GCHandle.Alloc(onRfidNotify);

callbackSet = new CallBackSet()
{
    RfidNotifyEvent = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(onRfidNotify),
    RfidStatusEvent = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(onRfidStatus),
    ScannerNotifyEvent = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(onScannerNotify),
    ScannerStatusEvent = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(onScannerStatus)
};

callbackPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(callbackSet));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(callbackSet, callbackPtr, false);

OpenScannerSDK(IntPtr.Zero, callbackPtr, ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue porting other C DLL to C# some years ago.

Function pointers in C# are represented as delegates. Internally, delegates are class instances and they're collected by GC the same way other objects are collected.

Probably in your DLL there's some method that "stops" the API, making it stopping invoking the C++ function pointers. You must call this before you close the application.

Probably your app collects the delegate objects and when the C++ DLL tries to invoke from unmanaged code, finds an invalid object reference.

It's interesting to keep the references in C# of these delegates in private fields, to avoid them to be collected when the application is running. The sympton of this issue is that the application crashes intermitently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was my thought also, and the CloseScannerSDK function is supposed to do exactly that, release the callback pointers you pass with OpenScannerSDK. The problem is CloseScannerSDK executes correctly and then the crash happens when my app tries to exit. 

I also though there might be a bug with the code in the C++ library (not releasing the pointers correctly), but the C++ demo app that uses the library works. However, it uses LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary when it works with the DLL. Maybe if I do the same and release the library before the app exits, this will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing I found that actually OpenScannerSDK always returns True, which made me believe it was working correctly, but it may not be the case. I did several tests, including passing a TCallBackSet struct that does not have any members and OpenScannerSDK still returned True.

So it seems the problem is with TCallBackSet and these delegates. Something's wrong there. I tried passing the CallBackSet w and w/o ref, no difference. Noticed int in C++ is not the same as int in C#, so changed functions signatures to use short instead of int. None of these made any difference.